# Local Storage crash when retrieving array

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, crash, xcode5

I cannot understand why my app is crashing and how can I avoid it,

in .h

```
  @property (nonatomic)  NSArray * PersonsFromSearch;
```

in .m

crash zone

```
 viewDidLoad
NSArray* nameArr;
   if([defaults objectForKey:@"Person1"])
   {
       nameArr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [defaults objectForKey:@"Person1"],Nil];//ate
       PersonsFromSearch = nameArr;//crashes here  :(
       NSLog(@"not crashed yet");
   }
```

in same file assignment to the local storage

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self dismissKeyboard];
    //test solution :)
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];//store it !
    [defaults setObject:[PersonsFromSearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]     forKey:@"Person1"];//store 1 person Full details
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];//store indeed
    //keep with code
}
```

crash detail:

2013-11-10 08:50:47.938 RevealControllerProject[1375:a0b] -[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe008a00

2013-11-10 08:50:47.942 RevealControllerProject[1375:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe008a00'

*** First throw call stack:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use    `PersonsFromSearch =[NSArray arrayWithArray:nameArr];`

Comment: Just checked and yes it is a valid. it is too long so i won't paste it here

Comment: {
    Address = "";
    CellPhone = "";
    EMail = "bnetanyahu@knesset.gov.il";
    EnglishPerson = "";
    FaceBookLink = "";
    Fax1 = "02-5303367";
    Fax2 = "";
    FileNAme = "114961.jpg";
    HomeEMail = "";
    HomeFax = "";
    HomePhone1 = "";
    HomePhone2 = "";
    PersonID = 114961;
    PersonName = "\U05d1\U05e0\U05d9\U05de\U05d9\U05df \U05e0\U05ea\U05e0\U05d9\U05d4\U05d5";
    Phone1 = "02-6753227";
    Phone2 = "";
    ZipCode = "";
}
thats what inside of it

Comment: This is a dictionary not an array i think

Comment: I used it and got same exemption :(

Comment: I have NSArray of items like that , and in my search engine it works

Comment: try logging nameArray

Comment: just did , nameArr is valid

Comment: `NSArray * nameArr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [defaults objectForKey:@"Person1"],Nil];//ate
    NSLog(@"%@",nameArr);`

Comment: how can i know in what exactly row i crash ?

Comment: How do you instantiate `defaults` in viewDidLoad? Are you sure you are not declaring it as an NSArray* by mistake?